# Can't receive mqtt message published to topic with AWS.Lambda+AWS.IOT

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-iot

To Send Message I use AWS.Lambda+AWS.IOT

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({"endpoint": 'XXXXXX'});
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  var params = {
        topic : "testtopic/action1",
        payload : "payload",
        qos: 0  
    };
  iotdata.publish(params, 
    function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else     console.log(data);          
    }
  );
};
```

Some time I receive messages (with wrong order or big delay), but usually any messages at all.

For receive messages I use AWS.Console -> AWS IoT -> MQTT client

What wrong with my lambda?

Comment: This is the code running inside Lambda right? After publishing each message do you invoke callback to properly exut the Lambda?

Comment: @Ashan yes, lambda execute right

Comment: Try calling the callback(Third variable after context) of context.succeed method in lambda to properly exit its execution after the publish event is successful